# SQL - Access-VBA self-merge table data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a very disorganized table from a legacy system. It looks like this:

```
ID  | ProjArea | Task | SumDays | AI | SDLC | DEV | PT | CS | ENG |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
239 |    A     | SDLC |   2     |    |   2  |     |    |    |     |   
239 |    A     | DEV  |   3     |    |      |  3  |    |    |     | 
239 |    A     | AI   |   8     | 8  |      |     |    |    |     | 
239 |    A     | PT   |   2     |    |      |     | 2  |    |     | 
239 |    B     | DEV  |   4     |    |      |   4 |    |    |     | 
239 |    B     | AI   |   2     | 2  |      |     |    |    |     | 
239 |    B     | PT   |   2     |    |      |     | 2  |    |     | 
71  |    B     | DEV  |   5     |    |      |   5 |    |    |     | 
71  |    B     | AI   |   2     | 2  |      |     |    |    |     | 
71  |    A     | PT   |   2     |    |      |     | 2  |    |     |
```

From the table above, we can see that it is very redundant having the task as a column and a task column. I am designing a query that merges the data in one column instead of multiple for each project Area.

Expected End result looks like this:

```
ID  | ProjArea | SumDays | AI | SDLC | DEV | PT | CS | ENG |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
239 |    A     |   15    | 8  |   2  |  3  | 2  |    |     |   
239 |    B     |    8    | 2  |      |  4  | 2  |    |     | 
71  |    A     |    2    |    |      |     | 2  |    |     | 
71  |    B     |    7    | 2  |      |  5  |    |    |     |
```

I have tried a full outer join on the table itself and still havent been able to achieve this. Any ideas or hint on how to achieve this? 
I am writing VBA code to attempt this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want with an aggregation query:

```
select id, projarea, sum(sumdays) as sumdays,
       sum(ai) as ai, sum(sdlc) as sdlc, sum(dev) as dev, sum(pt) as pt,
       sum(cs) as cs, sum(eng) as eng
from t
group by id, projarea;
```